# How to override Kafka topicId in Lagom Service descriptor

Tags: apache-kafka, lagom

I am trying to figure out how I can override Kafka topicId in Service descriptor. 
My client has single Kafka cluster used for DEV & QA. But Kafka topic id is hardcoded in service descriptor. So all dev & QA instances of application post events in this topic.

Is there any way to define topic id in application.conf and use it Service descriptor?

Answer (score 0):

Add in the `application.conf` code like this:

```
topic = "default-topic-name"
topic = ${?ENV-VARIABLE-TOPIC-NAME}
```

This option in config allow as to use neither default value for this key or value from the environment variable. It means that for each environment you can have different topic names.

In api module write following code:

```
val config = ConfigFactory.load()

withTopics(topic(config.getString("topic"), kafkaTopic))
```

Here we are loading config and find by key name value for this key and put it as topic name.